I want to hide the bottom navigation bar in nested sub routes using the go_router package
I have the following routes:
|_ShellRoute
|_GoRoute /homescreen (requires bottom navigation)
|_GoRoute /homescreen/productdetails/:id (does not requires bottom navigation)
|_GoRoute /cartscreen (requires bottom navigation)
I want to hide the navigation bar when I am on productdetails screen. I dont want the navigation bar on that screen. How can I do it.
Here is the code:
Routing File:
enum AppRoute {
  home,
  product,
  cart,
}

// private navigators
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorHomeKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Home');
final _shellNavigatorCartKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'Cart');

final router = GoRouter(
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    // Home Route
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (context, state, navigationShell) =>
          ScaffoldWithNavBar(navigationShell: navigationShell),
      branches: [
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorHomeKey,
          routes: [
            // home route
            GoRoute(
              path: '/',
              name: AppRoute.home.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: 'product/:id',
                  name: AppRoute.product.name,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    final id = state.pathParameters['id']!;
                    return ProductDescriptionScreen(id: id);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),

        // cart route
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorCartKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/cart',
              name: AppRoute.cart.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const CartScreen(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

Screen Where Implementing Bottom Navigation Bar
class ScaffoldWithNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;
  const ScaffoldWithNavBar({super.key, required this.navigationShell});

  void _goBranch(int index) {
    navigationShell.goBranch(index,
        initialLocation: index == navigationShell.currentIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: navigationShell,
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        destinations: const [
          NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), label: 'Cart'),
          NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Account'),
        ],
        onDestinationSelected: _goBranch,
        selectedIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I am not getting any idea How to Implement it.
Here is homescreen picture:
HomeScreen Image
I want bottom navigation bar here and it is implemented.
and here is CartScreen:
CartScreen Image
I want bottom navigation bar here and it is implemented.
and here is ProductDescriptionScreen:
ProductDescriptionScreen Image
I don't want bottom navigation bar here. I want to remove it from this screen.
I have read some articles on how to hide or remove the bottom navigation bar while navigating to child routes, but none of the solutions are working for me. I am currently stuck and unsure of how to proceed.
Here is a link to the issue I posted on Stack Overflow, but I have not been able to resolve it yet: Bottom Navigation Bar Issue

The routes look like this:
_ShellRoute 
|_GoRoute /homescreen (requires bottom navigation) 
|_GoRoute /homescreen/productdetails/:id (does not requires bottom navigation) 
|_GoRoute /cartscreen (requires bottom navigation)

Sorry for messing up in start

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
